# how to merge a single directory in two git branches?

Tags: git, merge, directory

Two branches have diverged. We wish to manually merge two directories into one.
This is not the case where one branch has a directory completely not present in the other. In that case we could use git checkout.

We want to merge, and then manually merge changes where there is a conflict.

Comment: Did you try using `git merge`?

Comment: What does "merge two directories" mean?

Comment: And what does "merge a single directory" mean?